# $4^{2020} - 2020$ mod $48$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> $4^{2020} - 2020$ mod $48$

**My Approach:**

I basically tried to separate $4^{2020}$ into multiple entities and tried to break them down but at one point it just wasn't computational.

Comment: Try separating $48$ with the Chinese Remainder Theorem instead.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: $4^{\large 2+N}\! \bmod 48 = 4^{\large 2}(4^{\large N} \bmod 3) = 4^2(1)\,$ by the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), and by $\bmod 3\!:\ 4\equiv 1\Rightarrow 4^N \equiv 1^N\equiv 1\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$4^{2018}\equiv1\pmod{3}$
implies
$4^{2020} \equiv 16\pmod {48}$

Comment: wouldn't $4^{2020}$ mod $3$ be equal to $1$ as well?

Comment: Yes, it would. But that doesn't help when mod 48. Indeed $16\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: right. I think this answers the question so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$4^{3}\pmod{48}\equiv4^{2}\pmod{48}$